# How can I add hover text to images of a basic gallery on wordpress elementor?

Tags: gallery

I have a basic gallery of images. I want to add a caption that is only visible on hovering over the images of the gallery.

Comment: What did the Elementor user guide/documentation say about this?  Have you asked the Elementor devs?  Elementor is a third-party plugin and not a part of WP core so it's technically off topic - WPSE is intended to be used for people to post code problems relating to WordPress so that other developers can offer assistance rather than being a "how to use" for every third party plugin which should be maintaining it's own support channels and documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Your question doesn't show any code examples or tell me a lot about what you want to show in the caption, so I'll leave that out and make up my own code.

Here is one way to show a caption on hover using jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/steckinsights/yzfpg7n0/25/

Now, doing this with a gallery means that you'll need to do a lot more to this (looping through the images, wrapping the image and the caption in an element, adding a unique ID or class to the image and caption) but this is a basic answer to your question of how it could be done.

One of many ways including:

- Set image as BG image and use the `::after` CSS element to display comment
- Loop images with PHP and pull comment from alt tag using jQuery
- Use one of many plugins that do this out of the box
- etc.

Comment: @vaibav-sharma Could you share some sample code or links to what you're developing so we can provide a useful answer?  I believe my answer is useful in reference to the limited information you provided.